# Change beamer margin for images

Tags: beamer, graphics, pdftex, margins

I want to insert image that covers entire beamer tile, no margin or extra white space is desired.

Current MWE

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
    \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Title}
    \begin{flushleft}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{CtrlSM1.pdf} 
    \end{flushleft}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This gives me,[image: Current output]

But what I desire is,[image: Desired output]

I have tried,`\begin{flushleft} Image \end{flushleft}`, `\hspace{-5mm}`
and`\vspace{-3mm}`

Can you please suggest some modifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `flushleft`, just put the picture in a box of `textwidth` width. Make sure the height is also suitable, I don't have your PDF to check.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
    \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Title}
    \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image]